# How to implement a floating action button with a changing icon in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, mobile

I am new to Flutter, I am working on a project, in the app  I want to have a floating action button that dynamically changes its icon based on a certain condition.

For example, when the status is true, it should display a ✔️ icon, and when the status is false, it should display a ❌ icon.

I've tried the `FloatingActionButton` widget, but it seems to only support a static icon.

How can I achieve this dynamic icon behaviour for the floating action button?

I would appreciate any guidance or code samples to help me implement this functionality!

This is my progress so far:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool? isConditionTrue; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Floating Action Button Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Your App Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isConditionTrue = !isConditionTrue;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          isConditionTrue ? Icons.check : Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me on DartPad. Please provide a [mcve] or provide more details about the environment you're running this in.

Comment: Each time your condition variable change, you call setState and your UI will be updated. I ran your code and it works like a charm. Still don't get your point? What's your problem again?

Comment: Welcome to the Statckoverflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For trying dynamic icons, try this code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  List<IconData> icons = [
    Icons.done,
    Icons.cancel,
    Icons.turn_right_outlined,
    Icons.king_bed,
    Icons.alarm,
    Icons.one_k,
  ];

  int activeIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Floating Action Button Demo'),
      ),
      body: const Center(
        child: Text(
          'Your App Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            if (activeIndex < icons.length - 1) {
               activeIndex++;
            } else {
              activeIndex = 0;
            }
          });
        },
        child: Icon(icons[activeIndex]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(const MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}
```

Hope this will help.
Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track but you could improve your code by making your `isConditionTrue` variable a boolean instead of a `boolean?`. Using `!isConditionTrue` on a variable that can be null is likely your problem. Think about this - if `isConditionTrue == null`, what would you expect the result to be? `!null` is undefined.

There are only two states needed for `isConditionTrue` - `true` and `false`. If you assign `isConditionTrue` an initial value and make it a simple boolean, you'll have better results.

Here's your code modified to fix this, but note that you could potentially set `isConditionTrue` to `true` to start if you'd rather.

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isConditionTrue = false; 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Floating Action Button Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Your App Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isConditionTrue = !isConditionTrue;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          isConditionTrue ? Icons.check : Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to define initial values for boolean value **isConditionTrue**  **true** or **false**.Because **Boolean** values takes **Null Nullable** value.

***Like this:-***

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool isConditionTrue = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Floating Action Button Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Text(
          'Your App Content',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          setState(() {
            isConditionTrue = !isConditionTrue;
          });
        },
        child: Icon(
          isConditionTrue ? Icons.check : Icons.add,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MaterialApp(
    home: MyHomePage(),
  ));
}
```